# Get touch speed / velocity and move box2d body at this touch position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone, uitouch

I make one box2d game and I have some problem based on touch.

I desired one box2d body object moves on touch with speed / velocity.

I have an Ant box2d body with revolute joint and I try to move that box2d body object with touch and speed of touch. But I have no idea for that.

**Ant body**

[image]

I am also a new developer in Box2d.

please help me.... for solving this issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat velocity = ccpSub(position, previousPosition);
CGFloat speed = ccpLength(velocity);
```

Comment: You get position/previousPosition from the touch location. Velocity you can set directly on the Box2D body.